# Set with roots of $x^{p^{q}}-x$ is $\mathrm{GF}(p^q)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-fields

If $\mathrm{GF}(2^6) = \mathbb{Z}_2 [x]/ (x^6 + x + 1)$ and $u$ is a generator with $o(u)= 63$  how do I show  $\mathrm{GF}(2^3)=\{0,1, u^9, u^{18}, u^{27}, u^{36}, u^{45}, u^{54}\}$?

Here's what I came up with: Since $\mathrm{GF}(2^3)$ is the set of roots of $x^8-x$, if the set were equal to $\mathrm{GF}(2^3)$ each element would satisfy $f(x)=x^8-x=0$.

$f(u^9) = (u^9)^{8} -u^9 = u^9-u^9 =0 $

$f(u^{18}) = (u^{18})^8 -u^{18} = u^{18}-u^9 =0$

etc. 
Is that sufficient for $\mathrm{GF}(2^3)=\{0,1, u^9, u^{18} ,u^{27}, u^{36}, u^{45}, u^{54}\}$ or is there something else to show? Maybe something with $\mathbb{Z}_2 [x]/ (x^6 + x + 1)$? In general, if a set contains all roots of $x^{p^q}-x$ is the set always equal to $\mathrm{GF}(p^q)$?

Comment: Yes, the field of $p^r$ elements is the splitting field over the field of $p$ elements of the polynomial $x^{p^r}-x$.

Comment: Yes, you have successfully identified the unique copy of $GF(8)$ inside $GF(64)$. For that purpose nothing else needs to be done. Only if you need to construct an explicit homomorphism of fields from, say, $\Bbb{Z}_2[x]/\langle x^3+x+1\rangle$ to your copy of $GF(2^6)$, then you need to do more. Like figure out the minimal polynomial of $u^9$.